# OPENXML to extract data from XML and add to the table

Tags: sql, openxml

I have a XML file from where I want to get the data and place it into the SQL table. My problem is the path is different in the same XML file.

For an example,

one path = `'root/DescriptorRecord/DescriptorName'`

second path = `'root/DescriptorRecord/ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term'`

I have no clue that how to get a value from two different path in a same XML.

Following is my XML :

```
<root>
<DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
  <DescriptorName>
   <String>abc</String>
  </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>abc</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>pqr</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>xyz</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 <DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
  <DescriptorName>
   <String>Numerics</String>
  </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>123</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>456</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>789</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 </root>
```

My SQL query :

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT Descriptor, Terms
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/DescriptorRecord/DescriptorName')
WITH 
(
 Descriptor [varchar](100) 'String',
 Terms [varchar](100) 'String'
)

  SELECT Terms
  FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/DescriptorRecord/ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term')
  WITH 
  (
    Descriptor [varchar](100) 'String'
    Terms [varchar](100) 'String'
  )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Result :

[image: http://imgur.com/wvS1pNL,JpApXuQ]

Expected Result

[image: http://imgur.com/wvS1pNL,JpApXuQ#1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, setting up your sample in a variable:

```
DECLARE @X XML =  N'<root>
<DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
  <DescriptorName>
   <String>abc</String>
  </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>abc</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>pqr</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>xyz</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 <DescriptorRecord DescriptorClass = "1">
  <DescriptorName>
   <String>Numerics</String>
  </DescriptorName>
  <ConceptList>
   <Concept PreferredConceptYN="Y">
    <TermList>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="Y"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="Y">
        <String>123</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="N"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>456</String>
     </Term>
     <Term  ConceptPreferredTermYN="N"  IsPermutedTermYN="N"  LexicalTag="NON"  PrintFlagYN="Y"  RecordPreferredTermYN="N">
        <String>789</String>
    </Term>
   </TermList>
   </Concept>
  </ConceptList>
 </DescriptorRecord>
 </root>'
```

You'll want to select the descriptors first in an inner query, and return the results to an outer query, where you can use the descriptor column as a xpath criteria in the second .nodes() call. Like so:

```
SELECT Descriptor.Data.value('./DescriptorName[1]/String[1]','nvarchar(200)') AS Descriptor, Terms.Data.value('.','nvarchar(200)') AS Terms
FROM @x.nodes('root/DescriptorRecord') Descriptor(Data)
    cross apply Descriptor.Data.nodes('./ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term/String') Terms(Data)
```

EDIT: An attempt to make it less computationally expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I got my solution with XPath but I used it different way. SELECT Descriptor,Terms
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/DescriptorRecord/ConceptList/Concept/TermList/Term')
WITH 
(
  Descriptor [varchar](100) '//DescriptorName/String',
  Terms [varchar](100) 'String'
)

Comment: This solution gives me the expected results. One question I have is, this only creating descriptor columns  but I also want second column named Terms. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know exactly how you're not getting the terms. See this [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38380) for results.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is giving me the terms but I was talking about about column header. This example have very small data but in actual I have a 300 MB worth XML file with this format. Is there any quicker way to get the results? Currently I am running this solution and it just gives me 190 records in last 53 mins and still it is running!!!!!

Comment: 300 MB is a lot, but should be done by now. Try my edit, if it's still not terribly fast, then I recommend putting the imports in a table and taking advantage of [SQL Server's XML Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx).

Comment: This one is also slow. Currently I have break down that huge XML file into muliple XML file. I mean to say, the above example has two records like that I have break that file into multiple records. It has 27149 records. Is there any way that I can use this records to achieve my desired output?

Comment: To be frank, There's no quick way to handle 27149 xml elements in T-SQL in anything that could be considered "fast". As I mentioned before, try putting the incoming document into a table that has an XML index on the target column. This may increase the speed.